# DELL XPS13 Sound Output Popup

Tags: windows, audio, speakers, headphones, dell-xps

My Dell XPS 13 won't play through my headphones, just the speakers. Before, when I inserted the headphones, a popup would appear asking me where I wanted the sound to go through. Stupidly I disabled the popup. how do i get it back???

Answer (score 2):

Just right click on speakers icon in the taskbar and select Playback devices. Here you can select the current playback device which in your case is headphones. You can also select headphones to be default device so that you don't have to select it every time you connect the headphones.